# Resources.getIdentifier() Generates Resource IDs

Tags: android, android-resources

If I understand the documentation correctly, a call to `Resources.getIdentifier()` returns 0 in case the resource with `name` doesn't exist. An emulator with API level 8 works that way.

However, if I use an emulator with API level 16 it creates a new id for me. I can even call `Resources.getResourceName()` on it to get the name I used in `Resources.getIdentifier()`. If I call `Resources.getString()` it throws an exception.

```
int resourceId;
// both calls return the same value:
resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("com.testthisout:string/idontexist", null, null);
resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("idontexist", "string", "com.testthisout");
// with API-level 8 resourceId is 0.
// with API-level 16 it's something like 0x7f07005f now.
resources.getResourceName(resourceId);     // returns "com.testthisout:string/idontexist"
resources.getString(resourceId);           // BANG!!!

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f07005f
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:313)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:341)
    <my method here, no nested exception or something>
```

`Resources.getIdentifier()` returns incrementing numbers for all further calls to it with non-existing resource names and apparently it stores them somewhere.

I've already created a fresh emulator from scratch and still have the same behaviour. I have tests with robolectric in a different project (that is linked into my main project just like their guide explains), but it doesn't help if I close that project (I thought that their shadowing mechanism somehow causes issues). Cleaning and rebuilding the project doesn't help, there is no warning or error.

I need this functionality as I'm working with generic resource names and some more logic in the background.

Is this behaviour expected? Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @NKijak Sadly that didn't help. It calls `native final int getResourceIdentifier(String type, String name, String defPackage);` in `android.content.res.AssetManager`. The source of that would be interesting. But thanks for checking.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?  I am facing a similar situation.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Nope, haven't been coding Android for over two years.